# primeng confirmation service multiple calls

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, primeng

I am using PrimeNg with Angular 6 to generate a confirmation box on deleting an item from a form, and saving all changes made to the form. When

```
delete() {
  this._confirmationService.confirm({
     message: 'Delete Item?',
     key: 'delete',
     accept: () => {
       // code to delete row
     }
  });
}

submit() {
  this._confirmationService.confirm({
     message: 'Save Changes',
     key: 'submit',
     accept: () => {
       // code to save changes
     }
  });
}
```

html

```
<button pButton (click)="delete()"></button>
<button pButton (click)="submit()"></button>

<p-confirmDialog key="delete"></p-confirmDialog>
<p-confirmDialog key="submit"></p-confirmDialog>
```

When not using a key, both buttons call the submit confirm function. While using keys, the submit button calls the submit confirmation but gets stuck in a loop when accepted, and the delete function calls the submit confirmation then, if rejected, calls the delete confirmation.

What do I need to do so only the confirmation service specific to the function is called?

Comment: did you find your solution bro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

HTML:

```
<button type="button" (click)="delete()" pButton icon="pi pi-check" label="Delete"> 
</button>

<button type="button" (click)="submit()" pButton icon="pi pi-times" label="Submit"> 
</button>

<p-confirmDialog ></p-confirmDialog>
```

TS:

```
submit() {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure that you want to proceed?',
        header: 'Confirmation',
        icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
        accept: () => {
            //message here
        },
        reject: () => {
            //message here
        }
    });
}

delete() {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Do you want to delete this record?',
        header: 'Delete Confirmation',
        icon: 'pi pi-info-circle',
        accept: () => {
            //message here
        },
        reject: () => {
            //message here
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when rejecting the confirmation dialog, I had to click like 10 times to exit the dialog.
It turns out that I was simply missing the `confirmationService.close()` on the reject event:

```
confirmDelete(index: number): void {

    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure you want to delete the parameter?',
      accept: () => {
        this.deleteParameter(index);
      },
      reject: () => {
        this.confirmationService.close();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: this worked for me as well.

Comment: worked also for me in Angular 14. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:
HTML:

```
<p-confirmDialog id="deleteSelecteddomains" key="multiple" [style]="{width: '450px'}"></p-confirmDialog>

<p-confirmDialog id="deleteDomain" key="single" [style]="{width: '450px'}"></p-confirmDialog>
```

TS:

```
deleteDomain(domain: Domain) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + domain.name + '?',
      header: 'Confirm',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      key:'single',
      accept: () => {
        this.domains = this.domains.filter(val => val.id !== domain.id);
        this.domain = {};
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Successful', detail: 'Domain Deleted', life: 3000 });
      },
      reject: () => {
        this.confirmationService.close();
      }
    });

  }

deleteSelectedDomains() {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure you want to delete the selected domains?',
        header: 'Confirm',
        icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
        key:'multiple',
        accept: () => {
            this.domains = this.domains.filter(val => !this.selectedDomains.includes(val));
            this.selectedDomains = null;
            this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Successful', detail: 'Domains Deleted', life: 3000});
        },
        reject: () => {
          this.confirmationService.close();
          this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Domains Deleted Failed', life: 3000});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the type on the buttons as "button" this will keep your browser from picking a type (IE generally picks the type of button, while others will pick submit). I would also suggest renaming your submit function as naming this submit may be overriding the default submit event that the submit buttons are tied to.